# Array transformation tree structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, tree, binary, binary-tree

I have an array that needs to be converted to a tree structure, and I've searched for some scenarios, such as the following code, but once the amount of data is too large, the time required to generate this tree structure seems too long, ask if there can be a better solution or optimization!

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, name: 'A', parentId: 0 },{ id: 2, name: 'B', parentId: 1 },{ id: 3, name: 'C', parentId: 2 },{ id: 4, name: 'D', parentId: 3 },{ id: 5, name: 'E', parentId: 4 },{ id: 6, name: 'F', parentId: 5 },{ id: 7, name: 'G', parentId: 6 },{ id: 8, name: 'H', parentId: 7 },{ id: 9, name: 'Z', parentId: 8 }];

var toTree = function(data) {
  var map = {};
  data.forEach(function(item) {
    map[item.id] = item;
  });
  var val = [];
  data.forEach(function(item) {
    var parent = map[item.parentId];
    if (parent) {
      (parent.children || (parent.children = [])).push(item);
    } else {
      val.push(item);
    }
  });
  return val;
}
console.log(toTree(data))
```

Comment: How many items are in your array ? what "too long" means : does it cause browser to hang, or just too long for your personal taste ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a single loop approach where `id` and `parentId` is used for building a tree in the same loop.

At the end return the root node's children.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, name: 'A', parentId: 0 }, { id: 2, name: 'B', parentId: 1 }, { id: 3, name: 'C', parentId: 2 }, { id: 4, name: 'D', parentId: 3 }, { id: 5, name: 'E', parentId: 4 }, { id: 6, name: 'F', parentId: 5 }, { id: 7, name: 'G', parentId: 6 }, { id: 8, name: 'H', parentId: 7 }, { id: 9, name: 'Z', parentId: 8 }],
    tree = function (data, root) {
        var o = {};

        data.forEach(function (a) {
            a.children = o[a.id] && o[a.id].children;
            o[a.id] = a;
            o[a.parentId] = o[a.parentId] || {};
            o[a.parentId].children = o[a.parentId].children || [];
            o[a.parentId].children.push(a);
        });
        return o[root].children;
    }(data, 0);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to change your data in the first place, so that it does not come from an array but a tree structure map and data map:

```
var treeStructure = {
   'ROOT': ['childId1', 'childId2'],
   'childId1': ['childId3']
}
var data = {
   'childId1': {
      'property1':1 
   },
   'childId2': {
      'property1':2
   },
   'childId3': {
      'property1': 3
   }
}
```

This is so that the relationship of parent-child will be very clear and it will be very easy to find each item.